# What does a JList use for effectively displaying its elements?

Tags: java, list, model, jlist, renderer

This was a question at a java test I took. The question was the one in the title. 
I answered 'a model'. Apparently, I was wrong and  the answer is 'a renderer'. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The model just holds the data which you want to display. The renderer takes the objects from the model and displays them in your list. It defines how the object values are displayed.

See [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer):

> A list uses an object called a cell renderer to display each of its
>   items.